# How to run my project jar file outside of Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

In netbeans my project executes successfully but when I click clean and build option to create jar file for my project. A folder "dist" is created where the jar file of my project exists. Further i copy the database file of the project into "dist" folder. When i double click that jar file it prompts two times i.e,

```
1. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

2. java.lang.NullPointerException
```

After this the jar file executes fine but the data from the database is not displayed on the table[table is there in my project to retrieve some values from database]. I passed through a couple of same questions but found no solution. Please help me, I am a bigginer need your guidance as simple as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify META-INF file (in the project) to have following entries. More information can be found [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/olaf/entry/jdev_including_a_classpath_in).

***Main-Class***

The Main-Class tag is useful for an application packaging with the main class defined, but not telling the user. To start the application you usually issue something like java -jar application.jar. One of the well known examples is java -jar oc4j.jar. To specify the Main-Class tag in your MANIFEST.MF you need to include the following line:

```
Main-Class: path.to.your.application.Main
```

***Class-Path***

The Class-Path tag is useful for specifying the list of the libraries application needs to successfully run. You can specify the class path like any other but use the blank character (' ') as the path separator. Ie. no colon (':')or semicolon (';') as for the Un*x/Linux or Win environments, respectively.
To specify the Class-Path tag in your MANIFEST.MF you need to include a line like the following:

```
Class-Path: lib/ojdbc14.jar lib/log4j.jar
```

Then package/create jar --> Open jar using Winzip/WinRAR and navigate to META-INF to make sure those entries are there.

After that copy jar to some folder (wherever you would like to run), for example: `C:\myfolder`.  Create a lib folder under `C:\myfolder`. Copy required JDBC jars to `C:\myfolder\lib`. That should make your code run.

Regarding `NullPointerException`, you need to make sure your code properly handles `null` case. There is no magical solution to this issue except, make sure reference is NOT `null` (or) wrap the probelmatic code inside `try/catch` block

Comment: I have already specified the main class but still the jar file shows these two errors

Comment: i used ms access as database